# Storing and accessing the heigh and width of an image using 'size' in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, vector, indexing

I need the height and width of an image in Matlab. The following lines do that.

```
rgbImage = imread('peppers.bmp');
disp(size(rgbImage));
```

Output: Image size: 
            69   100     3

Next I wanted to print(store) only one of them. So I did

```
Imgsize=size(rgbImage);
disp(Imgsize(0));
```

which throws me the following error: 'Attempted to access Imgsize(0); index must be
a positive integer or logical.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `Imgsize(1)` , In matlab indexing starts from 1 not 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB is not 0-indexed. Arrays indices start at one so you need to do 'disp(ImgSize(1))'